# Swift - keeping two properties in sync

Tags: swift, properties, synchronization

In Swift, I have two related properties of a structure that I want to keep in sync.

I'm currently doing this with property observers but I've had to add an extra flag to prevent them playing an infinite game of ping-pong with each other.

Is there a more elegant and/or transparent way to achieve this?

A simplified example:

```
import Foundation

struct Angle {
    var blockPropertyObservers = false
    var degrees: Double {
        willSet(degrees) {
            print("will set degrees to \(degrees)")
            if !blockPropertyObservers {
                blockPropertyObservers = true
                radians = (degrees / 360) * 2 * M_PI
            } else {
                blockPropertyObservers = false
            }
        }
    }
    var radians: Double {
        willSet(radians) {
            print("will set radians to \(radians)")
            if !blockPropertyObservers {
                blockPropertyObservers = true
                degrees = (radians / (2 * M_PI)) * 360
            } else {
                blockPropertyObservers = false
            }
        }
    }
    init(inDegrees degrees: Double) {
        self.degrees = degrees
        self.radians = (degrees / 360) * 2 * M_PI
    }
    init(inRadians radians: Double) {
        self.radians = radians
        self.degrees = (radians / (2 * M_PI)) * 360
    }
}
```

Ideally, I'd also like to find a way to avoid having to replicate the code for the conversions in the `init()` routines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a computed property for one of those two, let's say for degrees. This will reduce the boiler plate code, without losing functionality for your struct.

```
struct Angle {
    var degrees: Double {
        get { return radians / (2 * M_PI) * 360 }
        set { radians =  (newValue / 360) * 2 * M_PI}
    }
    var radians: Double = 0.0
    
    init(inDegrees degrees: Double) {
        self.degrees = degrees
    }
    init(inRadians radians: Double) {
        self.radians = radians
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - yes I initially had it like this but I would really prefer to avoid the unnecessary recalculation on-the-fly every time the `degrees` value is read because in the real case that's quite a heavy duty job :(

Comment: ah - now that's a feature of the language that's new to me! +1 to you :)

Comment: I need to test that but if I understand correctly, if I do `init(inDegrees:)` and then read `angle.radians` wouldn't I get zero?

Comment: my understanding is that property observers don't get called when you change a property from within an `init()` handler though?

Comment: Perfect! Wish there was some easy way in Swift to achieve the same.